# Fine tune a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have to List all `customers` and the `number of orders` placed by each
- Return `CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderTypeName and OrderCount` in `CustomerName` order.

this is my query, it is returning desired result.
can i rewrite it in a better way or is it correct ??

Also do i always have to give all the fields in `Group by` clause, if i don't it throws error.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID,
       c.CustomerName,
       ot.OrderTypeName,
       Count(o.CustomerID) OrderCount
FROM   tblCustomer c
       LEFT JOIN tblOrder o
              ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
       LEFT JOIN tblOrderType ot
              ON o.OrderTypeID = ot.OrderTypeID
GROUP  BY c.CustomerID,
          c.CustomerName,
          ot.OrderTypeName
ORDER  BY c.CustomerName;
```

Comment: I can't speak for the other RDBMSs, but in MySQL, this is fine. MySQL permits the omission of columns in the aggregation, but it's not good practice.

Comment: I want to write in SQL server

Comment: This looks fine imo.

Comment: can anyone explain why i always have to give all fields in group by, i only wish to group by Customer name, but had to give remaining fields so that it doesn't give error.

Comment: In most RDBMSs, you have to specify all fields in the GROUP BY, except those you aggregate, As a workaround, you can write `SELECT max(c.CustomerID) as CustomerID, c.CustomerName , max(ot.OrderTypeName) as OrderTypeName, COUNT(o.CustomerID) as OrderCount`

Comment: Im guessing customerid is the Primary Key and,if so,just remove it from both select and GROUP BY and use `COUNT(*)`.otherwise you have a working query which doesnt do much.

Comment: if you want to count the no. of all orders placed by customer then you don't need `ordertypename` in `group by`

Comment: If you only want to group by c.CustomerName then how would you expect it to deal with more than one ot.OrderTypeName for a c.CustomerName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping means that you will get one record per group. For example. Consider you have table Orders(OrderID, CustomerID, Price). And you are grouping by CustomerID. Suppose you have in your table following records:

```
1 1 100
2 1 200
3 1 300
4 2 50
5 2 50
```

So you have two customerID - 1 AND 2. Grouping by Costomer means that you will get two rows as a result

```
1
2
```

So if your select is

```
Select CustomerID from Orders
group by CustomerID
```

you can select CustomrerID because you have 2 CustomerID and so do grouping. When selecting

```
Select CustomerID, Price
From Orders
Group By CustomerID
```

what do you think SQL Server will return as Price for customer 1 or 2?
you have 3 choices for customer 1 and 2 choice for customer 2. SQL Server don't know which of this choices you want to get. That's why you must provide select statement with aggregate function like SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX which will produce 1 result from possible choices.

In your select you can do following:

```
;With cte as(
Select CustomerID, OrderTypeID, Count(*) As Cnt from Order
Group by CustomerID, OrderTypeID)
Select c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, ot.OrderTypeName, cte.Cnt from Customers c
left join cte c on cte.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Join tblOrderType ot on cte.OrderTypeID = ot.OrderTypeID
```

Comment: Is this way of writing the query more CORRECT. Also, if the count cnt is 0 in the 1st query it returns NULL in the final output, is there a way to display 0 if the values of count is NULL?

Comment: added ISNULL function to convert to 0